# Cannot Amend Boot Order

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, bios

I have a HP DC7800 running Windows 7 SP1 and when I restart I am shown a screen with Attempting Boot from USB device and an error with "no such partition", followed by Entering rescue mode and then Grub Rescue. I then have to enter Boot setup and tell it to boot from hard drive. However if I try to to change the Boot Order so that it starts by booting form the hard drive it just does not seem to accept when I go to save and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a USB plugged in, if yes then just unplug it. Otherwise there should be an option in BIOS settings to boot off your hard drive before trying a USB.